# A day without Mouse (Java keyboard Shortcuts)

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Today I decide to make a resolution which consist of testing my **Java** application using the **keyboard** solely.

But I am faced with some obstacles:

1. How do you select/deselect a checkbox using the keyboard?
2. How do you collapse/expand items in a `JTree`?

All help will be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example of a checkbox I want to select:
[image]

**PS:** space didn't work

Comment: tab.. tab.. tab... space, normally does the trick - though seems a pointless *resolution*

Comment: If you learn something new, it is not pointless then ;)

Comment: looks like you are using a custom renderer? if so, you'll need to add some sort of action listener methinks...

Comment: The problem is this tree is generated by another **DEV team**, and I am only able to view it not edit it. Even **collapse/expand** does not interact with **space**. Is there any way I can do it directly with the keyboard without listeners?

Comment: hmm, may be you can try the left/right arrows to expand, if space does not select the checkbox, then you'll need submit a bug report to the dev team to fix it.

Comment: Submit your last comment as an answer and I will accept it. The left/right arrows worked

Comment: well-behaved ui applications _must_ be usable equally well by both mouse and by keyboard. Unfortunately, many neglect the keyboard interaction, so a big fat +1 for the question :-) Implementing that interaction (most probably, don't know your role in the team) is the task of the dev team. If done properly, the keystrokes should be the same as used in native application in the OS - searching the gui guidelines of the OS might help to find them (if the dev team didn't document them ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra apparently, space select/deselect checobkox outside this tree. The only problem I am having is selecting a checkbox inside the Tree

Comment: don't know how native OS behave in that context, if you find any that does react to space by toggling the selection inside the tree, you know what to do: as @Nim already suggested file a bug against the dev team :-)

Comment: The errant implementation could be [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxNodeTreeSample.htm), which ignores keystrokes and also defeats the (default) multiple selection capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer question #2, you can either press <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> keys from the NUMPAD, or use <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> arrow keys to collapse and expand trees.

Comment: I could not make it happen with any keyboard sequence. I feel this is a shortcoming of this control for accessibility. The other option is an OS-specific Accessibility Options, such as Windows "Mouse Keys" feature to move and click the mouse with the NumPad.